# python libxml2 serialization problem

Tags: python, serialization, xml-serialization, libxml2

I'm having some problems while attempting to serialize a libxml2 object in python.

In particular, if I run :

```
xmlstring = cdoc.serialize('UTF-8', 1)
```

where cdoc is a libxml2 document created before,

I have something like this : ( on a mac - port python 2.5.6)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <journal>
      <journal_metadata language="en">
        <full_title>Contributions of Lick Observatory</full_title>
        <issn media_type="print">1750-0095</issn>
        <coden>CoLic</coden>
      </journal_metadata>
    </journal>
</body>
```

while on Linux (Centos 5.6 with python 2.4 or 2.6) I have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <journal>
      <journal_metadata language="en">
        <full_title>
Contributions of Lick Observatory
        </full_title>
        <issn media_type="print">
1750-0095
        </issn>
        <coden>
CoLic
        </coden>
      </journal_metadata>
    </journal>
</body>
```

There is a problem in the indentation of the string node.

Now I could solve this by doing :

```
xmlstring = cdoc.serialize('UTF-8')
```

without the option for the indentation, but the output format is not very readable.

Is there a way to fix the awkward indentation of the output?

Comment: What is the version of libxml2 on both platforms ?

Comment: On mac it is libxml2_2.7.8 and py25-libxml2_2.6.21; on CentOS 2_2.6.26

Comment: Ok... I think that the problem is the version of libxml2... I tried on Centos6 with libxml2 2.7.something and it works fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that I was running:

```
xmlstring = cdoc.serialize('UTF-8', 2)
```

and not

```
xmlstring = cdoc.serialize('UTF-8', 1)
```

This, for some reasons, on libxml2 2.6 indents also the text node and on libxml2 2.7 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a behaviour difference between the version of libxml2 on the different machines. Try upgrading the oldest one to the newer release (or a more recent one).

Comment: converting the comment on the question above to an answer so that the question can be marked as answered.